# Invalid configuration Location

Tags: lubuntu

I was working by my laptop last night and everything was working great. I woke up today and turn it on. But when I wanted to open one of my software from terminal (ampl) I got this error:

```
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system

Gtk-Message: 11:57:53.068: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent.   This is discouraged.
```

and a big error windows that say :  Invalid configuration Location

```
 the conficguration area at ... could not be created .please choose a writable location using configuration command line option
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`